# May-to Many Relation with Sorting Coluomn in joining Table not updating the index always zero

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to save many-to-many relationship with extra fields in the joining table.
My Entities are Custom_Event and Custom_Actions and CustomEventAction.

"Custom_Event can have many Custom_Actions and Custom_Actions Can have many Custom_Event"

Problem is CustomEvent, Custom_Actions and CustomEventAction are getting saved, but the sort value is setting zero for all the time.

As per my Testing method it insert two Custom_Actions to the CustomAction table and the CustomEventAction but the sort value is zero all the time (attached image of sql output!

[image]
This my hibernate xml mapping

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping package="com.apps.cms.customevents.domain">

        <class name="CustomEvent" table="custom_event">
            <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
            <id name="id" type="long" column="event_id" unsaved-value="0">
                <generator class="native" />
            </id>
            <property name="name" column="name" />
            <property name="description" column="description" />
            <property name="onceOnly" column="once_only" type="yes_no"
                not-null="true" />
            <property name="stepCompletionSequential" column="step_completion_sequential"
                type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="helpTxtStyle" />
            <many-to-one name="site" class="com.Site"
                column="site_id" not-found="ignore" />
            <property name="createdBy" column="created_by" />
            <property name="created" column="created_date" />
            <property name="lastModifiedBy" column="last_modified_by" />
            <property name="lastModified" column="last_modified_date" />

            <list name="eventActions" table="custom_event_actions" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <key column="action_id" not-null="true" />
                <index column="sort" />
                <one-to-many  class="com.apps.cms.customevents.domain.CustomEventActions" />
            </list>

            <property name="deleted" column="deleted" type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
        </class>


        <class name="CustomAction" table="custom_action">
            <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
            <id name="id" type="long" column="action_id" unsaved-value="0">
                <generator class="native" />
            </id>
            <property name="name" column="name" />
            <property name="description" column="description" />
            <property name="helpTxtStyle" />
            <many-to-one name="site" class="com.Site"
                column="site_id" not-found="ignore" />
            <property name="customForm" column="custom_form_id" />
            <property name="showStatus" column="show_status" type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="showTimeOccurance" column="show_time_occurance"  type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="showComments" column="show_comments" type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="hasCustomStatus" column="has_custom_status" type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="allowReset" column="allow_reset" type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="deleted" column="deleted" type="yes_no" not-null="true" />
            <property name="createdBy" column="created_by" />
            <property name="created" column="created_date" />
            <property name="lastModifiedBy" column="last_modified_by" />
            <property name="lastModified" column="last_modified_date" />
        </class>


    <class name="CustomEventActions" table="custom_event_actions">
        <composite-id name="eventActionId" class="com.apps.cms.customevents.domain.CustomEventActionId">
            <key-many-to-one name="customEvent"  class="com.apps.cms.customevents.domain.CustomEvent" column="event_id" />
            <key-many-to-one name="customAction" class="com.apps.cms.customevents.domain.CustomAction" column="action_id" />
        </composite-id>
         <property name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="id" />
         <property name="required" type="java.lang.Boolean" column="required" />
    </class>


    </hibernate-mapping>


Pojo's are


public class CustomEvent implements Serializable {
    private List<CustomEventActions> eventActions;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Site site;
    private CustomFormConstants.HelpTxtDisplayStyle helpTxtStyle;
    private boolean onceOnly;
    private boolean stepCompletionSequential;
    private boolean deleted;
    private long id;
    private Date created;
    private Account createdBy;
    private Date lastModified;
    private Account lastModifiedBy;


public class CustomAction implements Serializable {


    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAction.class);
    private CustomForm customForm;
    private boolean showTimeOccurance;
    private Set<CustomActionPlan> customActionPlans;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Site site;
    private boolean showStatus;
    private boolean showComments;
    private boolean allowReset;
    private boolean hasCustomStatus;
    private boolean deleted;
    private CustomFormConstants.HelpTxtDisplayStyle helpTxtStyle;
    private long id;
    private Date created;
    private Account createdBy;
    private Date lastModified;
    private Account lastModifiedBy;
}



public class CustomEventActions implements Serializable {

    private CustomEventActionId eventActionId = null;
    private boolean required;

    public CustomEventActions() {
        eventActionId = new CustomEventActionId();
    }
}


public class CustomEventActionId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CustomEvent customEvent;
    private CustomAction customAction;

}


TestingMethod:

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response creeateCustomEvent(@Context final HttpServletRequest request, final CustomEvent event) {
        Response.Status status = Response.Status.OK;
        Object jsonResponse = "";
        try {
            Account loggedUserAccount = Account.getAccount(request.getSession());
            if (loggedUserAccount != null) {
                if (event != null) {
                    event.setCreated(new Date());

                    List<CustomEventActions> customActionList = new ArrayList<CustomEventActions>();

                    CustomAction action1 = new CustomAction();
                    action1.setName("action1-" + event.getName());
                    action1.setDescription("description1-" + event.getName());
                    action1.setSite(App.getSite(request));
                    action1.setLastModified(new Date());
                    action1.setCreatedBy(loggedUserAccount);
                    action1.setLastModifiedBy(loggedUserAccount);
                    action1.setCreated(new Date());
                    action1.setSite(App.getSite(request));
                    action1.save();

                    log.info("action1-hashCode = " + action1.hashCode());

                    CustomEventActions customEventActions1 = new CustomEventActions();
                    customEventActions1.getEventActionId().setCustomEvent(event);
                    customEventActions1.getEventActionId().setCustomAction(action1);
                    customEventActions1.setRequired(false);
                    customActionList.add(customEventActions1);
                    log.info("customEventActions1-hashCode = " + customEventActions1.hashCode());

                    CustomAction action2 = new CustomAction();
                    action2.setName("action2-" + event.getName());
                    action2.setDescription("description2-" + event.getName());
                    action2.setSite(App.getSite(request));
                    action2.setLastModified(new Date());
                    action2.setCreatedBy(loggedUserAccount);
                    action2.setLastModifiedBy(loggedUserAccount);
                    action2.setCreated(new Date());
                    action2.setSite(App.getSite(request));
                    action2.save();
                    log.info("action2-hashCode = " + action2.hashCode());
                    CustomEventActions customEventActions2 = new CustomEventActions();
                    customEventActions2.getEventActionId().setCustomEvent(event);
                    customEventActions2.getEventActionId().setCustomAction(action2);
                    customEventActions2.setRequired(true);
                    customActionList.add(customEventActions2);
                    log.info("customEventActions2-hashCode = " + customEventActions2.hashCode());
                    event.setEventActions(customActionList);

                    event.setLastModified(new Date());
                    event.setCreatedBy(loggedUserAccount);
                    event.setLastModifiedBy(loggedUserAccount);
                    event.setCreated(new Date());
                    event.setSite(App.getSite(request));

                    customEventService.saveCustomEvent(event);
                    return Response.ok(event, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
                }
            } else {
                status = Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED;
                jsonResponse = "UNAUTHORIZED";
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            status = Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            jsonResponse = exception.getLocalizedMessage();
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Response.status(status).entity(jsonResponse).build();
    }

SQL:
CREATE TABLE `custom_event` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(400)  DEFAULT '',
  `once_only` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `step_completion_sequential` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `helpTxtStyle` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified_date`  datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`),
  key(site_id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




CREATE TABLE `custom_action` (
  `action_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(400)  DEFAULT '',
   `helpTxtStyle` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `custom_form_id` int(11),
 `show_status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
 `show_time_occurance` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
 `show_comments` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
 `has_custom_status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `allow_reset` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `deleted` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`action_id`),
   key(site_id)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `custom_event_actions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `sort` int(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `required` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES custom_event(event_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (action_id) REFERENCES custom_action(action_id)
)  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the eventActions list to be the inverse mapping side of the relationship. This means it won't own the database updates for the eventActions. This is the normal setup, for when you don't need to store an index id, since the child objects in a one-to-many association will have a foreign key back to the parent, it makes most sense for them to own the db updates for this foreign key, since it is in their table. However, whenever you need a sorted one-to-many association, you must make the "one" side of the association the owner of the asssociation, as only it knows what order the elements need to be in. (It isn't possible for an individual element to know what its order must be in a collection of elements.)

You need to remove the inverse from the one side of the collection, and make the many side inverse. To quote from "Java Persistence with Hibernate":

```
However, there is no inverse="true" for a many-to-one mapping so you need to 
simulate this attribute on a <many-to-one>:

<class name="Bid"
      table="BID">
   ...
   <many-to-one name="item"
column="ITEM_ID"
class="Item"
not-null="true"
insert="false"
update="false"/>
</class>
```

Comment: so you suggest me to remove the list entry and make it as "many-to-one'